# Select top n parent in a child based query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to limit the number of parents returned by this child table based query.

```
SELECT
    ch.Id AS childId,
    pr.Id AS parentId
FROM childTable ch
INNER JOIN parentTable pr ON ch.Id = pr.Id
WHERE
    1 = 1
ORDER BY pr.CreatedDate DESC
```

this should be a common need but i could not find the right words to describe it.

I have to return child records filtered by the where statement but limit the number of parents returned by the query.

Its like, get me the child records where .... , order them with the parent created date and only get the childrecords for top n parents.

I tried to get the row numbers but it counted the number of children

```
 ...ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY pr.Id ORDER BY pr.CreatedDate DESC) AS Row,
...
```

And i tried to group the records by parent but then i lose the detail info i need from the child table.

And i m using MS-SQL 2008

### Edit

Here is the [demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/17d04/6)

Explanation about the demo: the **PostAttachments** is the *child table* i mentioned before and the **Posts** is the *Parent*.

**Contents** table just joined for where statements and getting some columns from that table. But it's worth to add it to the demo for ContentId being a *part of the Composite key in PostAttachments*.

### Edit

Expected output for top 2 posts where (PostAttachment.xxxx = xxxx):

Say our where statement is true for Lines (1,3,5,7,8,9) on the following list...

(Line row is for referance to explanation only, its not on the db)

```
[Line]  POSTID  CONTENTID   CREATEDDATE                         TITLE   CONTENTTITLE
1       1       1           September, 25 2014 09:22:27+0000    post1   content1
2       2       2           September, 25 2014 09:22:27+0000    post2   content2
3       3       3           September, 25 2014 09:22:27+0000    post3   content3
4       4       4           September, 25 2014 09:22:27+0000    post4   content4
5       5       5           September, 25 2014 09:22:27+0000    post5   content5
6       1       6           September, 25 2014 09:22:27+0000    post1   content6
7       2       7           September, 25 2014 09:22:27+0000    post2   content7
8       3       8           September, 25 2014 09:22:27+0000    post3   content8
9       4       9           September, 25 2014 09:22:27+0000    post4   content9
```

So the result will have Rows with PostId of 1,3,5,2,3,4 but i just want top 2 of them ordered by TITLE

and the expected output in this conditions should have post1 and post2...

```
[Line]  POSTID  CONTENTID   CREATEDDATE                         TITLE   CONTENTTITLE
1       1       1           September, 25 2014 09:22:27+0000    post1   content1
2       2       2           September, 25 2014 09:22:27+0000    post2   content2
6       1       6           September, 25 2014 09:22:27+0000    post1   content6
7       2       7           September, 25 2014 09:22:27+0000    post2   content7
```

---

Tl;Dr; I need to cut the extra where and order by statements from [this demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2f271/33/0)

Comment: sample data would help to test..

Comment: @861051069712110711711710997114 ok preparing a fiddle

Comment: Can you show us the expected output ??

Comment: @KrishnrajRana added expected output with some explanation

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want.

```
SELECT
    pr.PostId AS POSTID
    ,Contents.ContentId
    ,ch.CreatedDate
    ,pr.Title AS Title
    ,Contents.ContentTitle
FROM PostAttachments ch
INNER JOIN Posts pr ON ch.PostId = pr.PostId
INNER JOIN Contents ON ch.ContentId = Contents.ContentId
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT TOP 2 PostId
    FROM PostAttachments
    GROUP BY PostId
    ) t ON ch.PostId = t.PostId
```

Also tested in your fiddle.

**Edited**

As per the further discussion. Check below query in the fiddle.

```
SELECT TOP 4 *
FROM (
    SELECT pr.PostId AS POSTID
        ,Contents.ContentId
        ,ch.CreatedDate
        ,pr.Title AS Title
        ,Contents.ContentTitle
        ,Contents.ContentType
    FROM PostAttachments ch
    INNER JOIN Posts pr ON ch.PostId = pr.PostId
    INNER JOIN Contents ON ch.ContentId = Contents.ContentId
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT PostId
        FROM PostAttachments
        GROUP BY PostId
        ) t ON ch.PostId = t.PostId
    ) a
WHERE a.ContentType = 0
ORDER BY a.Title DESC
    ,a.ContentId ASC
```

Comment: This gives the expected output only on given order and where statement. If i order the list by title descending. it still gets the post1 and post2, but it should get the post5 and post4 on the given example. I will try to improve fiddle a bit more to take where statement and ordering into consideration

Comment: Here i reloaded the demo http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2f271/3 and added example order and where statements

Comment: @Azadrum: Here postid 4 and 5 has `PostTypeId = 0`. So you'll never get data for top 2 records. Just replace top 2 with **top 6** and then you'll get data.

Comment: Yes i know and its because we are preselecting the top parent list without taking the main query results into consideration. I need the top n parents that made it through the main query filters

Comment: @Azadrum: Can you post the expected output in your question again on case-by-case basis.

Comment: Here i rebuilt the query from the long way. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2f271/33/0 this is what i really want but using same where / orderby statements twice is really ugly.

Comment: This is not selecting top n parents. This is just selecting top n results. As you can see it has only 2 parents in the result set while you tried to get 4. Nvm it. i ll try to update the question later on. But really thanks for your helps.